# Retrieving multiple values from a large jsonb field faster (postgresql 9.4)

Tags: postgresql, hstore, jsonb

**tl;dr**

Using PSQL 9.4, is there a way to retrieve multiple values from a jsonb field, such as you would with the imaginary function:

```
jsonb_extract_path(x, ARRAY['a_dictionary_key', 'a_second_dictionary_key', 'a_third_dictionary_key'])
```

With the hope of speeding up the otherwise almost linear time required to select multiple values (1 value = 300ms, 2 values = 450ms, 3 values = 600ms)

**Background**

I have the following jsonb table:

```
CREATE TABLE "public"."analysis" (
  "date" date NOT NULL,
  "name" character varying (10) NOT NULL,
  "country" character (3) NOT NULL,
  "x" jsonb,
  PRIMARY KEY(date,name)
);
```

With roughly 100 000 rows where each rows has a jsonb dictionary with 90+ keys and corresponding values. I'm trying to write an SQL query to select a few (< 10) key+values in a fairly quick way (< 500 ms)

**Index and querying: 190ms**

I started by adding an index:

```
CREATE INDEX ON analysis USING GIN (x);
```

This makes querying based on values in the "x" dictionary fast, such as this:

```
SELECT date, name, country FROM analysis where date > '2014-01-01' and date < '2014-05-01' and cast(x#>> '{a_dictionary_key}' as float) > 100;
```

This takes ~190 ms (acceptable for us)

**Retrieving dictionary values**

However, once I start adding keys to return in the SELECT part, execution time rises almost linear:

**1 value: 300ms**

```
select jsonb_extract_path(x, 'a_dictionary_key') from analysis where date > '2014-01-01' and date < '2014-05-01' and cast(x#>> '{a_dictionary_key}' as float) > 100;
```

Takes 366ms (+175ms)

```
select x#>'{a_dictionary_key}' as gear_down_altitude from analysis where date > '2014-01-01' and date < '2014-05-01' and cast(x#>> '{a_dictionary_key}' as float) > 100 ;
```

Takes 300ms (+110ms)

**3 values: 600ms**

```
select jsonb_extract_path(x, 'a_dictionary_key'), jsonb_extract_path(x, 'a_second_dictionary_key'), jsonb_extract_path(x, 'a_third_dictionary_key') from analysis where date > '2014-01-01' and date < '2014-05-01' and cast(x#>> '{a_dictionary_key}' as float) > 100;
```

Takes 600ms (+410, or +100 for each value selected)

```
select x#>'{a_dictionary_key}' as a_dictionary_key, x#>'{a_second_dictionary_key}' as a_second_dictionary_key, x#>'{a_third_dictionary_key}' as a_third_dictionary_key from analysis where date > '2014-01-01' and date < '2014-05-01' and cast(x#>> '{a_dictionary_key}' as float) > 100 ;
```

Takes 600ms (+410, or +100 for each value selected)

**Retrieving more values faster**

Is there a way to retrieve multiple values from a jsonb field, such as you would with the imaginary function:

```
jsonb_extract_path(x, ARRAY['a_dictionary_key', 'a_second_dictionary_key', 'a_third_dictionary_key'])
```

Which could possibly speed up these lookups. It can return them either as columns or as an list/array or even a json object.

**Retrieving an array using PL/Python**

Just for the heck of it I made a custom function using PL/Python, but that was much slower (5s+), possibly due to json.loads:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION retrieve_objects(data jsonb, k VARCHAR[])
RETURNS TEXT[] AS $$
  if not data:
    return []

  import simplejson as json
  j = json.loads(data) 

  l = []
  for i in k:
    l.append(j[i])

  return l

$$ LANGUAGE plpython2u;

# Usage:
# select retrieve_objects(x, ARRAY['a_dictionary_key', 'a_second_dictionary_key', 'a_third_dictionary_key']) from analysis  where date > '2014-01-01' and date < '2014-05-01'
```

**Update 2015-05-21**

I re-implemented the table using hstore with GIN index and the performance is almost identical to using jsonb, i.e not helpfull in my case.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the [`#>` operator](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-json.html), which looks like it performs a path search. Have you tried a normal `->` lookup?  Like:

```
select  json_column->'json_field1'
,       json_column->'json_field2'
```

It would be interesting to see what happened if you used a temporary table. Like:

```
create temporary table tmp_doclist (doc jsonb)
;
insert  tmp_doclist
        (doc)
select  x
from    analysis
where   ... your conditions here ...
;
select  doc->'col1'
,       doc->'col2'
,       doc->'col3'
from    tmp_doclist
;
```

Comment: For 3 columns, using `->` takes 560ms, vs 580ms with `#>`. Tried with temporary table, using `select x into ....` and then selecting from that doclist which takes 650ms

Comment: Does the timing for the temporary table change when you add/remove columns? 100ms seems outlandish for a dictionary lookup too, you'd expect to do that in nanoseconds.

Comment: It takes 200ms to create the temporary table, and then another 150ms for 1 value, 285ms for 2 values and 460ms for 3 values. I wonder if postgresql does json decoding for each lookup, but that shouldn't be the case (specially not for jsonb)

Answer (score 0):

This is hard to test without the data.
Create a custom type

```
create type my_query_result_type (
    a_dictionary_key float,
    a_second_dictionary_key float
)
```

And your query

```
select (json_populate_record(null::my_query_result_type,j::json)).*  from analysis;
```

You should be able to use a temporary table instead of type which will be created at, runtime making your query dynamic.
But first check it out if this helps form the performance point of view.

Comment: Ahh see now, this is a really old question, just stumbled upon it...